# Passing LinkedList<short[]> to a Constructor, will it work?

Tags: java, collections

I have class SpeexRunner as follows, The constructor of takes two arguments a boolean variable and a `LinkedList<short[]>`. As follows :-

```
public class SpeexRunner implements Runnable {
    public boolean stopThread;
    LinkedList<short[]> dataList;

    public SpeexRunner(boolean val_stopThread, LinkedList<short[]> dataRef){
        this.stopThread = val_stopThread;
        dataList = dataRef;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
     //add objects in dataList;
     // change / remove dataList Objects
    }
}
```

My Question is:- If I change the dataList inside the run(), will the changes be reflected to the original list which is declared somewhere else ?

Comment: Note: LinkedList is not thread safe. If you call run() in a different thread, you may or may not see the changes made to the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I change the dataList inside the run(), will the changes be reflected to the original list which is declared somewhere else ?

Yes. Your constructor receives a *reference* to the list, not a copy of it. If you want to copy it, you'll have to use the `LinkedList` [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList%28java.util.Collection%29). Then you'll have your *own* copy of the list. But note that the *entries* on the two lists are still shared, because the entries are arrays (`short[]`), and arrays are stored by reference.

This is perhaps best demonstrated by example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListExample {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        List<short[]> list;

        // Direct use (no copies)
        list = new LinkedList<short[]>();
        list.add(new short[] { 0, 0, 0 });
        System.out.println("list.size() before direct use: " + list.size());
        System.out.println("list.get(0)[0] before direct use: " + list.get(0)[0]);
        new DirectUser(list).doSomething();
        System.out.println("list.size() after direct use: " + list.size());
        System.out.println("list.get(0)[0] after direct use: " + list.get(0)[0]);
        // Output, note how both the list and its contents have been changed:
        // list.size() before direct use: 1
        // list.get(0)[0] before direct use: 0
        // list.size() after direct use: 2
        // list.get(0)[0] after direct use: 1

        // Copying the list, but note that the entries are shared by both lists:
        list = new LinkedList<short[]>();
        list.add(new short[] { 0, 0, 0 });
        System.out.println("list.size() before copy-list use: " + list.size());
        System.out.println("list.get(0)[0] before copy-list use: " + list.get(0)[0]);
        new CopyListUser(list).doSomething();
        System.out.println("list.size() after copy-list use: " + list.size());
        System.out.println("list.get(0)[0] after copy-list use: " + list.get(0)[0]);
        // Output, note how our list didn't change (it doesn't have a new entry), but
        // the entry at index 0 *was* changed:
        // list.size() before copy-list use: 1
        // list.get(0)[0] before copy-list use: 0
        // list.size() after copy-list use: 1
        // list.get(0)[0] after copy-list use: 1

        // "Deep" copying, both the list and its entries:
        list = new LinkedList<short[]>();
        list.add(new short[] { 0, 0, 0 });
        System.out.println("list.size() before deep-copy use: " + list.size());
        System.out.println("list.get(0)[0] before deep-copy use: " + list.get(0)[0]);
        new DeepCopyUser(list).doSomething();
        System.out.println("list.size() after deep-copy use: " + list.size());
        System.out.println("list.get(0)[0] after deep-copy use: " + list.get(0)[0]);
        // Output, note that neither the list nor its entries was affected by the call:
        // list.size() before deep-copy use: 1
        // list.get(0)[0] before deep-copy use: 0
        // list.size() after deep-copy use: 1
        // list.get(0)[0] after deep-copy use: 0


        System.exit(0);
    }

    static class DirectUser {
        List<short[]> items;

        DirectUser(List<short[]> items) {
            // DirectUser doesn't copy the list
            this.items = items;
        }

        void doSomething() {
            this.items.get(0)[0] = 1;
            this.items.add(new short[] { 2, 2, 2 });
        }
    }

    static class CopyListUser {
        List<short[]> items;

        CopyListUser(List<short[]> items) {
            // CopyListUser copies the list, but both lists still share items
            this.items = new LinkedList<short[]>(items);
        }

        void doSomething() {
            this.items.get(0)[0] = 1;
            this.items.add(new short[] { 2, 2, 2 });
        }
    }

    static class DeepCopyUser {
        List<short[]> items;

        DeepCopyUser(List<short[]> items) {
            // DeepCopyUser copies the list AND each entry
            this.items = new LinkedList<short[]>();
            for (short[] entry : items) {
                this.items.add(Arrays.copyOf(entry, entry.length));
            }
        }

        void doSomething() {
            this.items.get(0)[0] = 1;
            this.items.add(new short[] { 2, 2, 2 });
        }
    }
}
```

When `DirectUser` used the list, in our calling code we saw changes both to the list (in that it got longer) and to its contents (the first entry's first slot changed from `0` to `1`).

When `CopyListUser` used it, it made a *copy* of the list, so we didn't see any change to our list in our calling code (it didn't get longer). But we *did* see the change to the first entry (because both lists shared the same array object) — the first slot changed from `0` to `1` again.

When `DeepCopyUser` used it, it made a *copy* of the list **and** a copy of each entry, so things were completely and totally disconnected. No changes to the list or to its items were seen by our calling code.

Answer (score 3):

> If I change the dataList inside the run(), will the changes be reflected to the original list which is declared somewhere else ?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: Yes, because parameters are always passed by reference in Java.

(It is possible that you might use a (hypothetical) subclass of `LinkedList` that forbids or ignores changes.  In that cases, the attempted changes would result in an exception or would have no effect.  However, that would be perverse ...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will as the thread has a reference to the list, not a copy of the list. Note that `LinkedList` is **not synchronized**:

> If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Answer (score 2):

If you add elements to / remove elements from the list, the changes will be visible from the rest of your code. Note that if you use more than one thread, you will need to use synchronization to guarantee that the changes are visible.

If on the other hand you don't want the changes to escape your class, you could create a new List in your constructor and add all the items in the original list. In that case, changes to your list won't be visible from the outside, but if you make changes to the items in the list, those changes will be.